# How to call $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser() in Android

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

i am new to android and i am working on one application ,In which i have to add books by posting all book details to pHp server,here i am using httpPost call to send all book details,but  in pHp server there is a line,

```
    $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()
```

i cannot able to call it simply by httpPost in android..so i really need help to solve this problem..so please help me how to call it in android..thanks in advance....

this is the httppost used to send book details..

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            // replace with your url
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("www.example.com"); 


    //Post Data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("book", "name"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", "rate"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("author","author"));

    //Encoding POST data
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //making POST request.
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // write response to log
        Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

this is the php post function

```
    public function handlePOST($params, Request $request) {
    $book = new Book();

    if (isset($params['isbn'])) {
        $book->setIsbn($params['isbn']);
    }

    $book->setTitle($params['title']);

    if (isset($params['type'])) {
        $book->setFrequency($params['type']);
    }

    if (isset($params['period'])) {
        $book->setPeriod($params['period']);
    }

    if (isset($params['frequency'])) {
        $book->setFrequency($params['frequency']);
    }

    if (isset($params['type'])) {
        $book->setType($params['type']);
    }

    if (isset($params['author'])) {
        $book->setAuthor($params['author']);
    }

    if (isset($params['lang'])) {
        $book->setLang($params['lang']);
    }

    if (isset($params['pages'])) {
        $book->setPages($params['pages']);
    }

    if (isset($params['price'])) {
        $book->setPrice($params['price']);
    }

    if (isset($params['status'])) {
        $book->setStatus($params['status']);
    } else {
        $book->setStatus(1);
    }

    if (isset($params['bookCondition'])) {
        $book->setBookCondition($params['bookCondition']);
    }


    //$book->setAvailableFor($params['availableFor']);

    if (isset($params['description'])) {
        $book->setDescription($params['description']);
    }

    if (isset($params['genre'])) {
        $book->setGenre(json_encode($params['genre']));
    }
    // $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserBundle:User');
 //    $user = $repository->findOneBy(
 //                   array('id' =>$params['userid'])
 //          );

    //how to call below code    
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $user->setRewardPoints($user->getRewardPoints() + 10);
    $book->setCreatedBy($user->getId());

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($book);
    $em->flush();

   // $this->triggerBookChange($book->getTitle(), $params['type']);

    $response = new Response(json_encode($params));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: someone please answer my question.....

Comment: you need to explain more about the issue, what value this php line is supposed to return? post the relevant php code that involves calling this line, is it supposed to get the authorization token sent among the request? or is it the token stored for a user on the server side?

Comment: someone please answer my question.....